# Create 2 elements within a div

Tags: html, css

I need a create 2 elements within a block but for some reason the "Name" & "Bob" gets moved to a different line.

html

```
<div class=".div" style="padding-left: 50px">
        <h3 style="padding-right: 5px;float: left;padding-bottom: 23px;">Name:</h3>
        <span class="pt_name" style="block">Bob</span>
</div>
```

css

```
#div{
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:green
}
```

fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/LMKw7/
```

Answer (score 0):

The `h3` has implicit `margin-top` from the browser's default stylesheet, which is pushing it down.  Just set `margin-top: 0` and you'll see an improvement.

Also, I'd recommend using CSS rather than inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

You gived the styles to a div with an id `div` because you used `#` at the beginning.
If you want to add it to every div, simply use `div { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block;`

Also because of different font-size that `<h3>` and `<span>` has it appears that text within `<span>` is on new line.I have edited your fiddle.May be this may help you:

http://jsfiddle.net/LMKw7/2/

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

I had better luck setting "`display: inline-block;`" on the h3, rather than "`float: left`".

As for the "div" thing - you might confuse yourself by naming your selectors after element types. Anyway, classes generally don't have dots in them - the dot is just placed in CSS to select by class. The # tag is meant for IDs. So, the correct look would be this:

`<div class="myDiv" ...`

(CSS):

```
.myDiv {
```